# Как узнать что программу закрывает перезагрузка ПК, а не пользователь?

Tags: windows, delphi

Код написан на Delphi XE. В коде - при закрытии ПО - выдается запрос обычный (окно) - выход (y/n)?
При перезагрузке ПК\Срв стало спрашивать - есть не завершенные приложения, и как раз на него ссылаться - типа окно запроса (но уже при процедуре перезапуска, само окно не показывается).

Как и куда воткнуть в проект код в Form OnClose\Destroy чтобы ПО знало, что его не юзер закрывает, а идет рибут? И чтобы вопросов не задавало и завершалось.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/wm-endsession

Comment: Убрал лишние детали из вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При завершении приложения всегда вызываются события `TForm.OnDestory` и `TForm.OnCloseQuery`. При перезагрузке не вызывается событие `TForm.OnClose`, соответственно Ваше сообщение надо перенести в него.

Если требуется более сложная логика, то необходимо перехватывать сообщение *WinApi* `WM_ENDSESSION`, оно посылается при завершении работы *Windows*.

```pascal
TMyForm = class(TForm)
protected
  procedure WMEndSession(var Message: TWMEndSession); message WM_ENDSESSION;
end;
```

Comment: кажется, обработка WM_ENDSESSION это наоборот более простая логика.